# How to Copy all the files from one directory to another, and if file already exists then skip

Tags: ssis

I want to copy all files from one folder to another folder. But if that file already exists in the destination folder, it should be skipped.

I did that using Foreach loop with 'OverwriteDestination'="False" but failed to skip already present file.

How shall I accomplish the same?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your question, You might share which OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in a script task:

```
        string source = @"c:\";
        string dest = @"d:\";

        if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(dest))
        {
            //create directory and move all files
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dest);
            foreach (var file in new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(source).GetFiles())
                file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(dest, file.Name));
        }
        else
        {
            //Get file names in destination and only copy the unmatched files
            var destFileNames = new DirectoryInfo(dest).GetFiles().AsEnumerable().Select(f => f.Name);
            foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(source).GetFiles())
                if(!destFileNames.Contains(file.Name)) 
                    file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(dest, file.Name));
        }
```